# Why the data from Google analytics query explorer changes when I choose different date?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I set some parameters on the query explorer page, and I searched for the data on 2/23 and 2/24 respectively and searched the data from 2/23 to 2/24. The total number of 2/23 and 2/24 isn't equal to the number of 2/23 to 2/24.

Why the data is different?

Comment: Which numbers are don't match up? Some metrics (like unique visitors) count only once per report, so if a person returned, they might count for both single day reports, but only once for the combined report, for example.